# Voice control of audio playback: seek within track

Tags: music-player, voice-command, media-player

I'm planning a lengthy cycling trip and I'd like to be able to listen to language training mp3s while riding.  I think the ideal way to do this would be to use voice control.  Is there a way that will let me

- seek back eg 10 seconds
- seek back 1 minute
- repeat a section of, say 1 minute duration
- seek ahead 10s, 1m, etc
- skip to next/previous track
- pause/resume playback

via voice commands?

For bonus points, I'd like it to let me set a bookmark at a certain point in a given file and then seek to that spot via voice command.

Comment: Very interesting idea.